# How to configure two Mosquitto listeners with different protocols?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to enable websocket on mosquitto 2.0.11 in Ubuntu 22.04.
Here my `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`:

```
pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid
per_listener_settings true
password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwd_mqtt
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true

listener 1883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous false

listener 8080
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous false
```

Starting it with: `mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf -v` it outputs in `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`:

```
1707293771: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1707293771: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1707293771: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1707293771: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1707293771: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8080.
1707293771: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1707293771: Error: Address already in use
```

Why does it try to open again port 1883 on the second listener?

Comment: What files do you have in the `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` directory?

Comment: @hardillb the directory is empty

Comment: I can't reproduce this with 2.0.18 (and there are a bunch of security fixes in 2.0.16 that you should probably apply) A quick scan of the [change log](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt) doesn't show anything related, but I'd suggest an upgrade anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've duplicated this with Mosquitto 2.0.18:

```
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8080.
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
mosquitto-1  | 1707333576: Error: Address in use
mosquitto-1 exited with code
```

The issue appears to be that `password_file` is a `per_listener` setting, but in your config you have it placed above the `listener` lines, meaning that it applies to the default listener. To solve this either remove `per_listener_settings true` (it's not needed in your config as it stands), or move the `password_file` line i.e. (simplified things a little):

```
per_listener_settings true
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true

listener 1883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/pwd_mqtt

listener 8080
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/pwd_mqtt
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2497) for something similar.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It wasn't clear to me that `password_file` is a `per_listener` setting!

Comment: To be fair I feel that this is most likely a bug (the docs don't mention that this can happen). I've referenced your question in [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2991).